# SQL Server Merge replication: "Thread xxxx successfully re-established connection to Subscriber xxxxxx"

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have problems with SQL Server merge replication and it does not work.

Not so long ago, it was working. But recently we encountered this problem. And data transmission can not give up.

Setting timeout agent profiles raised and therefore do not have any transaction in waiting.

[image]

Comment: Question is not clear,what is your ask....?